# How to add playOrder in toc.ncx using XSLT?

Tags: xslt

If I decide to add a navpoint element in toc.ncx at the beginning of an existing toc.ncx in navmap, there is no way to reorder playOrder number but by hand. That could be really tedious if there are many navpoint elements.

Input

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ncx version="2005-1" xmlns="http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx/">
  <head>
    <meta name="dtb:uid" content="9781315348674" />
    <meta name="dtb:depth" content="1" />
    <meta name="dtb:totalPageCount" content="144" />
    <meta name="dtb:maxPageNumber" content="144" />
  </head>
  <docTitle>
    <text>Making Choices for Health Care</text>
  </docTitle>
  <navMap>
<navPoint id="nav-1">
<navLabel>
<text>Cover</text>
</navLabel>
<content src="xhtml/A01_cover.xhtml"/>
</navPoint>
<navPoint id="nav-2">
<navLabel>
<text>Half Title</text>
</navLabel>
<content src="xhtml/A02_halftitle.xhtml"/>
</navPoint>
</navMap>
</ncx>
```

Assuming Output Like:

```
<navPoint id="nav-1" playOrder="1">
      <navLabel>
        <text>1</text>
      </navLabel>
      <content src="Text/Section0002.xhtml"/>
    </navPoint>
    <navPoint id="nav-2" playOrder="2">
      <navLabel>
        <text>2</text>
      </navLabel>
      <content src="Text/Section0003.xhtml"/>
    </navPoint>
```

XSLT code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <!-- Recursive copy template -->    
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="navPoint">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="playOrder">1</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@playOrder">
        <xsl:attribute name="playOrder"><xsl:number count="*[@playOrder]" level="any"/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This code is not working and can you please tell me the correct code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
<xsl:attribute name="playOrder"><xsl:number count="navPoint" level="any"/>/xsl:attribute>
```

instead of

```
<xsl:attribute name="playOrder">1</xsl:attribute>
```

and remove template

```
   <xsl:template match="@playOrder">
    <xsl:attribute name="playOrder"><xsl:number count="*[@playOrder]" level="any"/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

See transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTyV/2

Comment: attribute is not added in particular element

Comment: @Lucky, See transformation at [https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTyV](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTyV)

Comment: sorry for the disturbance.
i'm updating the full code in input field.. in that case it will not work

Comment: you missed the namespace in xslt see [https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTyV/1](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTyV/1) now

Comment: @Lucky, for this you have also add id attribute, see [https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTyV/2](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTyV/2)

Comment: can you solve another Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50041282/how-to-add-the-mimetype-at-first-in-archive-in-multiple-epubs

Comment: is that any case without deleting remaing attributes and only add playOrder with sequence

Comment: add `<xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>` before add playOrder

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50302858/how-to-generate-ncx-using-html-in-xslt

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want normal 1,2,3 numbering, you could `count()` preceding nodes.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!-- Recursive copy template -->    
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="navPoint">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="playOrder">
          <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::navPoint) + 1" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: i want add specific attribute(playOrder) in element(navPoint)...
i'm trying to this code but no use..
any problem in my side... if you don't mind deep explanation required.

Comment: That's why you always need to add the expected output to your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50302858/how-to-generate-ncx-using-html-in-xslt